# Check_MK AWS monitoring - RDS checks not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, check-mk

I have configured AWS monitoring with Check_MK version 1.5.0p13 (following the documentation at the official Check_MK site). Everything works, except RDS checks, when I go to discover services, I get:

```
Service discovery failed for this host: 'DBName'
```

Is there anything I can do to debug this issue, where can I get some more output? Any ideas how to solve this?

This is the output of:

```
cmk -vI aws



WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds_summary': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds_summary", line 30, in parse_aws_rds_summary
    return {instance['DBName']: instance for instance in parse_aws(info)}
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds_summary", line 30, in <dictcomp>
    return {instance['DBName']: instance for instance in parse_aws(info)}


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds_summary': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds_summary", line 30, in parse_aws_rds_summary
    return {instance['DBName']: instance for instance in parse_aws(info)}
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds_summary", line 30, in <dictcomp>
    return {instance['DBName']: instance for instance in parse_aws(info)}


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)


WARNING: Exception while parsing agent section 'aws_rds': KeyError('DBName',)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/lib/python/cmk_base/data_sources/host_sections.py", line 260, in _update_with_parse_function
    return parse_function(section_content)
  File "/omd/sites/mysite/share/check_mk/checks/aws_rds", line 72, in parse_aws_rds
    parsed.setdefault(metrics['DBName'], metrics)
```

Comment: You may use the "--debug" option for more info. But have you looked for the "DBName" key that the error log pointing to? Do you have a host named "DBName"? It seems to me more like a configuration error somewhere. You haven't posted your config, so its difficult to tell.

Comment: Developers have contacted me, they debugged the problem with Werk #7362 that will be out today.

Comment: The developers have contacted you from the Serverfault post? Just curious.

Comment: @Diamant I have posted to their public mailing list, so I believe that is the point of the origin. In any way, great support from the team.

Comment: Ok. May be you can post it as an answer with a link to the bug fix page. This will help others visiting serverfault with similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug, where 'DBName' was used to identify the database, but that value was not always set. Now it uses 'DBInstanceIdentifier'.

Fixed in versions 1.5.0p14 and 1.6.0i1.

[Werk #7362](https://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk-werks.php?werk_id=7362&HTML=yes)

If you want to implement the fix, you can find the commit diff [here on the official Check_MK git repository](http://git.mathias-kettner.de/git/?p=check_mk.git;a=commit;h=4669f0b44c2cd857fa5aaf2f69bf5f6e77649f9a).